# How to fully shuffle TensorFlow Dataset on each epoch

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say I have a TensorFlow dataset defined as follows:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs, labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(50)
```

Every time a new batch of 50 is drawn from the dataset, it randomly samples 50 examples from the next 1000 examples. But what I want to do in addition to this, is to fully shuffle my entire dataset at the beginning of each epoch.

One way to do this would be to set the `shuffle_buffer` size equal to the size of the entire dataset. However, this would cause the entire dataset to be fully shuffled every time I draw a batch, which would be very slow. Instead, I only want the entire dataset to be fully shuffled once at the beginning of each epoch.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, this would cause the entire dataset to be fully shuffled every time I draw a batch, which would be very slow.

Not quite true. The whole buffer does not need to be shuffled each time a new sample is processed, you just need a single permutation each time a new sample comes in.

I did a small experiment and indeed did not find any significant impact of the size of the shuffle buffer on the computation time.

[image]

The penalty you pay for having a large shuffle buffer is actually memory-wise: having a shuffle buffer the size of your dataset means having your entire dataset in memory, which is not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

TF dataset operations are not all commutative, but if you apply `shuffle` before you apply `repeat` and `batch`, then TF should only shuffle the dataset once per epoch if your `buffer_size` is equal to your dataset size. You must also use the iterator properly to guarantee that you aren't reinstantiating it in your loop.